# Custom-columns of Endpoints in Kubernetes

Tags: kubectl, endpoint, customcolumn

Good day, thank you for your time.

I try to extract the custom column value from endpoints to get a name and IP address like this:

```
kubectl get endpoints -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,ENDPOINTS:subsets[0].addresses[0][0].ip
```

but I got no result, trying different combinations of this command.

The Endpoints format:

```
Name: "mysvc",
 Subsets: [
   {
     Addresses: [{"ip": "10.10.1.1"}, {"ip": "10.10.2.2"}],
     Ports: [{"name": "a", "port": 8675}, {"name": "b", "port": 309}]
   },
   {
     Addresses: [{"ip": "10.10.3.3"}],
     Ports: [{"name": "a", "port": 93}, {"name": "b", "port": 76}]
   },
]
```

Thank you for your time and attention.
Best regards
Andrei

Comment: Hi \`Andrei\` can you provide your yaml manifest file or some steps for replicating your deployment, so that we can replicate the same and try to find a solution.

Comment: Hi `Kranthiveer Dontineni`, thank you for answering. I have no deployments for this step. 

The whole idea is to see which pod belongs to which ingress in one table. Maybe you have an idea, would be glad to hear it. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want the `metadata.name` and all (!?) `ip`'s?

[`subset`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.27/#endpointsubset-v1-core) contains an array [`addresses`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.27/#endpointaddress-v1-core) so:

You can't `addresses[0][0]`

But you could `addresses[0].ip`

Or, if you want all of the IPs, you could `addresses[*].ip`

```bash
kubectl get endpoints \
--output=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,ENDPOINTS:subsets[0].addresses[].ip \
--all-namespaces
```

Or:

```bash
kubectl get endpoints \
--output=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,ENDPOINTS:subsets[0].addresses[*].ip \
--all-namespaces
```

Comment: Thank you, DazWilkin. 
But these commands also don't work, I tried them before also. That is why I am asking for help from the community because obviously, it looks like the correct syntax of commands that you wrote me.

Comment: Both commands in fact **do** work with `kubectl` and cluster at 1.28. What error do you receive from the commands? What versions of `kubectl` and cluster are you using?

Comment: Hello, DazWilkin.
You are right, thank you. It works in 1.28.
But I got cluster version 1.24. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is searching to accomplish the result of which ingress belongs to which pod there is the code:

```
import subprocess
import json
import pandas as pd


def get_kubectl_data(command):
    result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, text=True)
    if result.returncode != 0:
        print(f"Error executing '{command}': {result.stderr}")
        return None
    try:
        return json.loads(result.stdout)
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"Error decoding JSON from '{command}': {e}")
        return None


def main():
    # Fetching Ingresses
    ingresses = get_kubectl_data("kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces -o json")

    # Parsing data
    data = []
    for ingress in ingresses['items']:
        ingress_name = ingress['metadata']['name']
        namespace = ingress['metadata']['namespace']
        ingress_address = ', '.join([addr.get('ip', '') or addr.get('hostname', '') for addr in
                                     ingress.get('status', {}).get('loadBalancer', {}).get('ingress', [])])

        for rule in ingress.get('spec', {}).get('rules', []):
            hostname = rule.get('host', 'N/A')  # Extract hostname
            for path in rule.get('http', {}).get('paths', []):
                service_name = path.get('backend', {}).get('service', {}).get('name')
                if service_name:
                    # Fetching pods for each service
                    selector_data = get_kubectl_data(f"kubectl get svc {service_name} -n {namespace} -o json")
                    if selector_data:
                        selector = selector_data.get('spec', {}).get('selector', {})
                        selector_str = ",".join(f"{k}={v}" for k, v in selector.items())
                        pods = get_kubectl_data(f"kubectl get pods -n {namespace} -l {selector_str} -o json")
                        if pods:
                            for pod in pods.get('items', []):
                                pod_name = pod['metadata']['name']
                                data.append([pod_name, service_name, ingress_name, ingress_address, hostname])
                        else:
                            print(f"Skipping pods for service {service_name} as they could not be fetched.")
                    else:
                        print(f"Skipping service {service_name} as it could not be fetched.")

    # Creating DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Pod', 'Service', 'Ingress', 'Ingress Address', 'Hostname'])

    # Writing to Excel
    df.to_excel('k8s_data_prod.xlsx', index=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```